# How to add abline() to pareto.chart() / barplot()?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

[image]

I am using a this for pareto chart (library `qcc`):

```
## abcd is a data frame, and I am producing chart for column products
Product <- abcd$products
names(Product)<-abcd$customerid
pareto.chart(Product, ylab = "Number of Products", xlab="Customer", xaxt="n")
abline(v = 1000)
```

Since my data is huge I want to add `abline` after a interval of 10% to the x-axis but somehow I am not getting the lines.

Please let me know if some function could work here or is `abline` not allowed in pareto?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115144/discussion-between-abhishek-singh-and-zheyuan-li).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**pareto chart and bar plot**

`pareto.chart()` is based on `barplot()`, so as long as you know how to add `abline()` to `barplot()`, you know what to do with `pareto.chart()`. To demonstrate their relationship, consider the following:

```
## example from ?pareto.chart
defect <- c(80, 27, 66, 94, 33)
names(defect) <- c("price code", "schedule date", "supplier code", "contact num.", "part num.")
y <- pareto.chart(defect, ylab = "Error frequency")
barplot(0.2 * defect, add = TRUE, col = "grey")
```

[image: pareto and bar]

Now you can see that the bars coincide.

**Where are the bars?**

It is a pitfall that `pareto.chart()` does not return the location of those bars. Previously we have saved the result of `pareto.chart()` in `y`, now this is all `y` has:

```
> str(y)
num [1:5, 1:4] 94 80 66 33 27 94 174 240 273 300 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "contact num." "price code" "supplier code" "part num." ...
  ..$ Pareto chart analysis for defect: chr [1:4] "Frequency" "Cum.Freq." "Percentage" "Cum.Percent."
```

This is all that is going to be printed:

```
> y               

Pareto chart analysis for defect
                Frequency Cum.Freq. Percentage Cum.Percent.
  contact num.         94        94   31.33333     31.33333
  price code           80       174   26.66667     58.00000
  supplier code        66       240   22.00000     80.00000
  part num.            33       273   11.00000     91.00000
  schedule date        27       300    9.00000    100.00000
```

In this way, we have to call `barplot()` in order to get bars location:

```
x <- as.numeric(barplot(defect, plot = FALSE))
# > x
# [1] 0.7 1.9 3.1 4.3 5.5
```

Now if we do `abline()` on those positions:

```
pareto.chart(defect, ylab = "Error frequency")
abline(v = x, col = 2)  ## red
```

[image: abline]

**Adding `abline() / segments()` per 0.1 quantile**

I would suggest using:

```
x <- range(as.numeric(barplot(Product, plot = FALSE)))
x0 <- seq(x[1], x[2], length = 11)  ## 11 break points for 10 intervals
y <- pareto.chart(Product, ylab = "Number of Products", xlab="Customer", xaxt="n")[, 2]
y0 <- y[round(seq(from = 1, to = length(y), length = 11))]
## abline(v = v0, col = "purple")
segments(x0, rep(0, 11), x0, y0, col = "purple")
```

As a demonstration, I use

```
set.seed(0); Product <- rbinom(100, 20, 0.3)
```

[image: plot]